# How to decrement the month parameter and get the month text in rdlc vb.net report

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

i made a rdlc report in 6 months report of employees.my problem is, how to decrease a month parameter and getting  a previous months.that is if january is ma parameter value then january -1 = december

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to get the current month minus 6, you can simply do;

```
Now().AddMonths(-6)
```